# Distributed Backend REST API Polling

Tags: ios, rest, backend, distributed, polling

I am currently developing an iOS app where the app acts as a REST client making calls to a third party REST API.  The app makes calls in a polling fashion.  This works fine when the app is running in the foreground.  I am interested in polling this API in the background, but this kind of behavior isn't supported on iOS. The best solution I have come up with is to move the polling to a backend server and send push notifications to the iOS app.

Now my question is there any software available that would help with this kind of backend work?  Basically the software needs to poll the REST API for each user.  This could easily be distributed/parallelized, as the work isn't dependent on one another. I would also like it to be scaleable as the number of users increase. Are there any good frameworks or starting points for this type of work or am I stuck creating the whole thing?

Comment: Invest in making it event driven, not polled

Comment: Given that the REST API is from a third party, polling is the only option until they change their API.

Comment: There is a way to make a request in the background on iOS, however it is at the operating systems choice when you get to do so, and users can disable it, its called background refresh. See [this link for a tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/ios-7-background-app-refresh-tutorial/):

Comment: I've already researched the background task options. I need a reliable way to make calls to the REST API every x seconds.  The only way to do this is if you use a VoIP hack, where your app acts as a VoIP app to get a long running background task. Given my app doesn't provide VoIP functionality, Apple will surely rejected it.